# Retail Environment Reprovisioning Tool on VHD

Tags: dynamics-ax

What is the process of running Environment Reprovisioning tool on VHD environment.

I have restored the Database from UAT (Update 20) to Local VHD (Update 10.0.13)

The modules implemented in UAT are Finance, SCM, Payroll and Retail/Commerce.

I want to run Retail Retarget tool on the VHD. I have downloaded it from LCS and tried running it:
[image]

But I'm getting below error:

[image]

Is there a blog to explain how it can be run on VHD?

---------------Update1-----------

I followed this Blog Using the Retail Reprovisioning tool for Dynamics 365 for Operations – JohanPersson.nu

and ran the Runbook command but getting below error:

[image]

Appreciate any tips.

Regards,

Comment: The screenshots are so tiny the text cannot be even read.

Comment: Oops. I just copied and pasted. Will update tomorrow. Original here: https://community.dynamics.com/365/commerce/f/dynamics-365-commerce-forum/432749/retail-environment-reprovisioning-retarget-tool-on-vhd